# I am trying to understand what an expectation is

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, negative-binomial

Let $\{B_j(p) | j \geq 1\}$ be a sequence of Bernoulli trials or an i.i.d. sequence of Bernoulli$(p)$ random variables, where the win probability is

$$p = P\{B_j(p) = 1\} = E[B_j(p)].$$
Now define $X$ to be the negative binomial random variable that counts the wins within all the Bernoulli$(p)$ trial winning streaks until the first $\ell$ losses. This means that we can say that

$$X = \widetilde{B}_1(p) \oplus \cdots \oplus \widetilde{B}_{\ell}(p),$$
where $\widetilde{B}_j(p)$ is the $j$-th independent Geometric$(p)$ random variable. Your mission is to show that whenever $\ell \geq 1$, we have

$$E\left[1 - B_1(p) \mid X\right] = \frac{\ell - 1}{\ell - 1 + X}, \quad \text{hence} \quad E\left[\frac{\ell - 1}{\ell - 1 + X}\right] = 1 - p.
$$

Hint: Consider $E[B_j(p) \mid X = k]$ for all integers $j$ ranging from 1 to $k + \ell - 1$.

**what i have so far:**
For any discrete $Y$ that takes on the values $y_1,\ldots,y_n$, we define $E[X | Y]$ to be the random variable
$$
E[X | Y] \equiv \sum_{i=1}^n E[X | Y = y_i] \cdot \{Y = y_i\} = f(Y),
$$
where
$$
f(y_i) \equiv E[X | Y = y_i].
$$

Given this definition, we consider the conditional expectation of $B_j(p)$ given $X$:
$$
E[B_j(p) | X] = \sum_{i=1}^{k+\ell-1} E[B_j(p) | X = i] \cdot \{X = i\}
$$
This is effectively $f(X)$, where $f(x_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{k+\ell-1} E[B_j(p) | X = x_i] \cdot \{X = x_i\}$.

Thus, we have defined the conditional expectation to be that random variable. Now, we calculate the expectation of the conditional expectation:
\begin{align*}
E[E[B_j(p) | X]] &= E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{k+\ell-1} E[B_j(p) | X = i] \cdot \{X = i\}\right] \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{k+\ell-1} E[B_j(p) | X = i] \cdot E[\{X = i\}] \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{k+\ell-1} E\left[\frac{B_j(p) \cdot \{X = i\}}{P\{X = i\}}\right] \cdot P\{X = i\} \\
&= E\left[B_j(p) \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{k+\ell-1} \{X = i\}\right] \\
&= E[B_j(p)]
\end{align*}

But this should give me $\frac{k}{{k+\ell-1}}$ which it does not. What am i doing wrong?